# Proving that two quotient groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group isomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow H$, and a subgroup $K \subset G$, I need to show that there is a group isomorphism $G/K\cong H/\phi(K)$, where $\phi(K)=\{h\in H \,\,\text{such that}\,\,h=\phi(g)\,\,\text{for some}\,\,g\in K\}$.

I would like to use the fact that $G$ and $H$ have the same cardinality, and, likewise, that $K$ and $\phi(K)$ have the same cardinality, so that $|G/H| = |H/\phi(K)|$... But I am not sure how to prove that $K$ is isomorphic to $\phi(K)$.

Comment: You are not saying all your assumptions. You probably mean that $K$ is normal. Are you assuming the groups are finite?

Answer (score 2):

You need to assume that $K$ is normal in $G$, since otherwise the factor group $G/K$ need not exist. Then you need to show that normality is preserved under isomorphisms, and thus that $\phi (K)$ is normal in $H$. You can do this directly, or, using the fact that homomorphisms preserve normal subgroups in the codomain, this follows at once by noting that $\phi (K)=(\phi ^{-1})^{-1}(K)$ (since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, thus injective, and since $\phi^{-1}$ is a homomorphism (in fact an isomorphism)). Now you know that $G/K$ and that $H/\phi(K)$ exist. Now, consider the function $G\to H/\phi(K)$ given by $g\mapsto \psi (g)\cdot \psi (K)$. Is this a homomorphism? is it surjective? what is its kernel? what does the (first) isomorphism theorem tell you?